# Hola, en Github Actions tengo este problema en mi proyecto de flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, github-actions

Aluna manera de solucionarlo?, la carpeta build no aparece por defecto. Me refiero a cuando utilizo github actions to compile to android

> ##[error]Path does not exist /home/runner/work/t....r/t....r/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
>
> ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/home/runner/runners/2....0/bin/Runner.PluginHost', arguments 'action "GitHub.Runner.Plugins.Artifact.PublishArtifact, Runner.Plugins"'.

Comment: Me refiero a cuando utilizo github actions to compile to android

Comment: Sin ver el YAML del workflow que usas es difícil tener una idea de que puede estar pasando.